# Colleagues or Colleague's?

Tags: nouns, possessives

Here is the context:

*Please enter a colleagues email address:*

My coworker believes that in this context, it should be *colleagues*. I think that because it is a possessive noun, that it should be *colleague's*. I am no English expert, but I did learn about the use of apostrophes in public school... which version is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it should be *colleague's*, as it is their email address you are asked to enter.

Another way to phrase this would be *Please enter the email address of a colleague*; here the possessive is expressed through the *of*.

Comment: I love people who downvote answers just because they don't like the question.

Answer (score -3):

What do you want to indicate? `Colleague` in singular form, or to state that someone `has a colleague`?

Singular form:

`"Please enter a colleague email address"`

Possession form:

`"Please enter a colleague's email address"`

Plural form:

`"Please enter your colleagues email addresses"` (attention to the plural on `address` in this case).